# How to generate ebean model classes from existing MySQL schema (for Play 2.1)?

Tags: playframework, ebean

I've started using the Play 2.1 framework for the first time, and I would like to use ebean for the ORM to a MySQL 5.1 database.
I have successfully configured the DB connection using the Play 2.1 documentation, and I would like to reverse engineer my database schema into ebean model classes but can't seem to find any way to do this. I've read that it is possible to do this for 1.2.x but not for versions 2.x. I've tried the minuteproject website but it appears to only support the Play 1.2 implementation. 
I'm new to Play and ebean, I'm wondering if there's something fundamental that I have missed, otherwise could someone point me in the right direction? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Reverse engineered models are not possible in Ebean, unfortunately. You need to:

- Learn how the Ebean creates DB schema on some testing project, just by... testing
- Create models which will be able to work with your existing DB tables.
- Optionally modify your DB structure to make sure it's clear enough for Ebean

Other option (if possible) is to create new DB structure with Ebean plugin's support and then write some script (even with PHP) to migrate the data.

Sorry, that I can't give you better solution actually without good knowledge of your existing DB it's hard to say which approach will be better.